# jQuery wrap list without ul-tag from class to class

Tags: jquery, list

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="level2">
    <a  href="#" title="Betten">Betten</a>
</li>
<li class="level3">
    <a  href=#" title="">160cm</a>
</li>
<li class="level3">
    <a  href=#" title="">160cm</a>
</li>
<li class="level3">
    <a  href=#" title="">160cm</a>
</li>
<li class="level2">
    <a  href=#" title="">New Cat</a>
</li>
```

How can I wrap these element starting from .level2, all .level3 until the next .level2?

This is not wokring well:

```
$("li.level2").nextUntil("li.level2").andSelf().wrapAll('<ul>');
```

Comment: Codes working here: http://jsfiddle.net/H73eT/ isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a loop. Since your selector will select all `li.level2` elements andSelf() will add them all for wrapping. Also note that **[andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)** has been deprecated, use **[addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)** for 1.8+.

```
$("li.level2").each(function(){
     $(this).nextUntil("li.level2").addBack().wrapAll('<ul>');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKXEK/)**